# Getting result set from a statement block

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, scala, jdbc

I have a huge script with a lot of logic and with the `select statement` in the end which returns final result.

As many people know JDBC is not supposed to run SQL scripts (with multiple statements) out of the box so I wrapped script into `begin ... end` block making it a single statement block so that I can execute it in one go.

All seems to be good... except I can't get result set from `begin ... end` block (code below prints "No data"). So I had to split script into two pieces - all the logic (1) + final select statement (2).

```
val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + mssqlServer + ";integratedSecurity=true;"
val connMSSQL = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url)

val qqq0 = """begin
             |
             |if object_id('tempdb..#ttt') is not null drop table #ttt
             |
             |create table #ttt(i int, v varchar(10))
             |
             |insert into #ttt
             |select 0, 'qwerty' union all select 1, 'hello'
             |
             |select 1 id, 0 value
             |
             |end""".stripMargin

val qqq = "select * from #ttt"

val stmt = connMSSQL.createStatement()
stmt.execute(qqq0)
if (stmt.getResultSet==null) println("No data")
val rs = stmt.executeQuery(qqq)
```

The questions is - whether **there is any way to get result set from `begin ... end` block**? If the answer is no then the explanation would be highly appreciated.

PS. If I wrap all the code into procedure `my_proc` I can easily get result but creating objects in DB is not an option in my specific situation.

Works this way

```
val stmt1 = connMSSQL.createStatement()
stmt1.execute("my_db..my_proc")
val rs1 = stmt1.getResultSet
```

And this way as well

```
val stmt2 = connMSSQL.createStatement()
val rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("my_db..my_proc")
```

In both cases record set equals null when code is used with anonymous block instead of procedure.

PPS. No need to mention that if copy and paste `begin ... end` block into management studio and run it with F5 then it returns result without any problems.

**UPDATE**

For me behavior is still weird but luckily it works only with `set nocount on` AND `getMoreResults`.

However... it works for the firs statement only.

So if i include `nocount` into the original SQL script then for the code below

```
val stmt1 = connMSSQL.createStatement()
println(stmt1.execute(qqq0))
println(stmt1.getMoreResults())
if (stmt1.getResultSet==null) println("No data") else println("Yes data")

val stmt2 = connMSSQL.createStatement()
println(stmt2.execute(qqq0))
println(stmt2.getMoreResults())
if (stmt2.getResultSet==null) println("No data") else println("Yes data")
```

Output is following

```
false
true
Yes data
false
false
No data
```

**Now the question is how to get it working properly not for the first statement only.**

**UPDATE 2**

None of the links provided by moderator explain unexpected behavior with `createStatement`.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I wrote in the question, in case of `createStatement` it works for the first JDBC statement only and after calling `getMoreResults`.

For `prepareStatement` it works for all calls. Also it does not matter if I use `executeQuery` or `execute` + `getResultSet`.

```
val stmt1 = connMSSQL.prepareStatement(qqq0)
if (stmt1.executeQuery()==null) println("No data") else println("Yes data")

val stmt2 = connMSSQL.prepareStatement(qqq0)
println(stmt2.execute)
if (stmt2.getResultSet()==null) println("No data") else println("Yes data")
```

Output

```
Yes data
true
Yes data
```

**So the solution is - using `prepareStatement` and `set nocount on`.**

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CallableStatement` and `registerOutParameter`.

```java
val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + mssqlServer + ";integratedSecurity=true;"
val connMSSQL = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url)

val qqq0 = """begin
             |
             |if object_id('tempdb..#ttt') is not null drop table #ttt
             |
             |create table #ttt(i int, v varchar(10))
             |
             |insert into #ttt
             |select 0, 'qwerty' union all select 1, 'hello'
             |
             |select 1 id, 0 value
             |
             | ? := 123;
             |
             |end""".stripMargin

// val qqq = "select * from #ttt"

// val stmt = connMSSQL.createStatement()
// stmt.execute(qqq0)
// if (stmt.getResultSet==null) println("No data")
// val rs = stmt.executeQuery(qqq)

try (CallableStatement stmt = connMSSQL.prepareCall(qqq0)) {
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    stmt.execute();
    System.out.println(stmt.getInt(1)); // Display "123";
}
```

Comment: I need a **record set** as a result. Please check an update to original question. I managed to get it working but unfortunately it works for the first execution only.